# how to call global variable into vue component?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-component

i have this code in my master page. how this variable to be called in my vue template. i think the way i call the variable is wrong pls correct me

```
<script>
  window.App = {!! json_encode([
      'user' => Auth::user()->id,
  ]) !!};
</script>
```

and this is my vue template

```
<template lang="html">
  <div class="chat-message" v-if="message.user_from == window.App.user">
    <div class="chatright">
      {{message.user_from}} {{message.msg}}
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="chatleft" v-else>
    {{message.user_from}} {{message.msg}}
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will call it like so:

```
window.App.user.id
```

And by the way, in your master page you only need this:

```
<script>
  window.App = {!! json_encode([
      'user' => Auth::user(),
  ]) !!};
</script>
```

Comment: sir its say Property or method "window" is not defined on the instance and the app too. says Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'App' of undefined"

Comment: its already solve sir thank you very much. I appreciate your help. thank you

Comment: Thank you. and if you could please also vote upon the answer, much appreciated. @rookie

Comment: i have less than 15 reputation sir

Comment: Try now :) @rookie

Comment: Thank you :)  Have a greate day.